# How does package-info.java affect proguard (and why)?

Tags: java, android, sdk, proguard, package-info

If I have a class in an Android project that is in a package without a `package-info.java` file, the class can end up obfuscated as just `a` with members being `a`, `b`, `c`, ..., but adding a `package-info.java` file results in the class being obfuscated with the full package name, ex. `com.example.a`, and the members are `com.example.a.a`, `com.example.a.b`...

```java
package com.example;

enum class Something { THIS, THAT, OTHER }
```

I'm a fan, but I don't understand how/why this works. I also know that this can be accomplished by adding `-keeppackagenames` to the proguard rules file, but I'm delivering a library so I'd prefer to keep the change isolated to my new class that's causing a problem.